# Azure AD Powershell Get-AzureADUserMembership does not return all groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, azure-active-directory

`Get-AzureADUserMembership -objectid upn@mycompany.com` does not seem to return all groups. `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership upn` returns more groups. How to make sure these are in sync? Any reason why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-All` when you need all memberships:

```
Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId "user@example.com" -All $true
```

Also, remember that `Get-AzureADUserMembership` will only return the groups and roles a user is a *direct* member of, not the full transitive group membership list.

Comment: I guess I am interested in transitive group membership list. Any way to get that?

Comment: Any idea how to display all roles transitively?